# float input left in div

Tags: html, css

I have a captcha img that is max width 200px; and I want to put the input box flush beside it.. I have tried a to float the input left but got no result it still shows ontop of the input. this is inside a div row 12-large.

```
   <div id="captcha">
    <label>Captcha</label>
    <div>
    <img alt="captcha" src="captimg.php">
    <input class="sec" id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="captcha" value=""> 
    </div>                    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer help you

```
<div id="captcha">
<label>Captcha</label>
<div>
<img alt="captcha" src="captimg.php">
<input class="sec" style="width: 0px; z-index:0; height: 0px" id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="captcha" value=""> 
</div>                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using display:inline-block here

check this snippet

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div * {
  display: inline-block;
}
div#captcha {
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="captcha">
  <label>Captcha</label>
  <div>
    <img alt="captcha" src="captimg.php">
    <input class="sec" id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" placeholder="captcha" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```css
#captcha img,
#captcha .sec {
    float: left;
}
```

Use `float left` on both image and input. This will make them appear side by side.

Also, you have used `id="captcha"` twice in your code. `ID's should not be repeated`.